# Javascript string HTML composition

Tags: javascript, jqgrid-asp.net, jqgrid-formatter

I have this function that I use as a Custom Formatter in a JqGrid for ASP.NET WebForm

```
function formatLink(cellValue, options, rowObject) {
    var res = cellValue.split(" - ");
    var newLink = "";
    var value = rowObject['Filter'];
    var link = '<a class=\"clickCell\" href=\"#\" OnClick=\"CellClicked(\'value\')\">' + res[0] + '</a> - ' + res[1];
    newLink = link.replace("value", value).replace("'", "\'");
    return newLink;
}
```

the returned link does not work.

Here is an example:

```
<a onclick="CellClicked('vpd.esercizio = '2011-2012'')" href="#" class="clickCell">3</a>
```

As you can see, the `var value` contains string with quote. I will use its content to compose sql `where` condition.

Can you help me get things work?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply do

```
value.replace("'","\\'")
var link = '<a class="clickCell" href="#" OnClick="CellClicked('+value+')">' + res[0] + '</a> - ' + res[1];
```

?

With that replace you should be fine. I also removed some unnecesary back slashes because you can use double quotes inside simple quotes.

`document.write(' "" ');` returns  `""`

Comment: cause value usually containn somethig like vpd.esercizio = '2011-2012'

Comment: what's inside `value` and what it should be displayed? I think I misunderstood the question

Comment: As I wrote, value contains string with single quotes

Comment: can you manually write the string you want instead? you want to remove the single quotes or do you want to print them with a backslash?